# how to reduce the bitmap memory usage byte count but keep its dimensions

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

Searched and only find solutions for scale the bitmap to reduce its dimensions and size. But I am looking for a way to reduce the bitmap's memory byte count and don't change its dimension.

The images are from remote sources, they are not in our control. , after save the images to device locally, they will be shown as thumbnail later. Noticed it frequently throws OOM exception. The first step was to scale down the bitmap to a smaller dimensions when loading from the file (such as 500x500, or 300x300), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966) has some suggestions, which helps a little bit. 
A closer look find the scale downed bitmap may still have large byte count (from a few hundreds k to over one meg).

Since for this case the bitmap with lower resolution in memory should be ok, so is there a way it can keep the bitmap's dimensions but reduce it memory byte count?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read it in as `RGB_565` instead of `ARGB_8888`, to reduce the bit depth from 4 bytes/pixel to 2 bytes/pixel. However, that's all you can do, as the memory footprint of a `Bitmap` is the number of pixels times the bit depth per pixel.